# How would you combine a counter controlled loop with a flag controlled loop in c++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, counter

I am making a guessing the number game in c ++ and am asked to combine a counter loop with a flag controlled loop. I am using a random number generator and the minimum amount of times the user can guess is 5 times, after the user has guessed 5 times the program is supposed to respond with the number the computer generated. The only problem is that I haven't been able to successfully combined the counter with the flag loop, and when compiled, my program only asks the use for the guess and after it iterates 5 times it ends the loop and does not respond with the number the computer had generated. I'm pretty sure this has to do with how I arranged the counter controlled loop, but I am having trouble setting it up so that the counter is incremented within the flag controlled loop and providing a valid statement for the flag controlled loop. I tried searching up for more examples of flag controlled loop and counter controlled loops as I am fairly new to these concepts, but have not been able to fix my program.
Here is a part of my code:

```
while (!correct == (numGuesses < 5))
    {
        cout << "Guess the number the computer randomly picked between 1 - 100: ";
        cin >> guess;

        if (guess == number)
        {
            cout << "You guessed right, you win!" << endl << endl;
            correct = true;
        }
        else if (guess > number)
        {
        cout << "Sorry, your guess is too high" << endl;
        numGuesses += 1;
        }
        else if (guess < number)
        {
        cout << "Sorry, your guess is too low" << endl;
        numGuesses += 1;
        }
        else if (numGuesses == 5)
        {
            cout << "Sorry, you lost. The number is: " << number << endl << endl;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I believe your condition in the while-loop should be `!correct && (numGuesses < 5)`, since either of these cases would mean that you shouldn't continue.

The reason why you don't get the randomly generated number printed after 5 incorrect guesses is that you are using an `else if`. Since it is always the case that `guess == number`, `guess > number` or `guess < number` you never enter the last `else if`. Thus, change the last `else if` where you check if `numGuesses == 5` to a simple `if`-statement, and everything should work.

Comment: No worries. Could you mark my answer as correct, just for good measure? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> The only problem is that I haven't been able to successfully combined the counter with the flag loop

You have two conditions: `counter < limit` and `correct == false`.

You want to continue the loop so long as both conditions are true.

We have [logical operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) for combining boolean (true/false) expressions together.

In this case you want to say *X (is true) **and** Y (is true)* (the "is true" part is implicit in boolean expressions), which is spelled

```
X && Y
```

or in this case

```
(numGuesses < 5) && (!correct)
```